# How to make text svg-animation launch when visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have 3 sections on my page `

```
    <a href="#" class="next-section">Next Section</a>
    <div class="section-content">

    </div>
</section>

<section id="about">
    <a href="#" class="prev-section">Previous Section</a>
    <a href="#" class="next-section">Next Section</a>
    <div class="section-content">
        <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="480px" height="640px" viewBox="0 0 480 640" enable-background="new 0 0 480 640" xml:space="preserve">

<rect x="68.631" y="175.105" fill="none" width="350.877" height="113.158"/>
```

" SVG-PATHS HERE "

```
    </div>
</section>

<section id="services">
    <a href="#" class="prev-section">Previous Section</a>
    <div class="section-content">

    </div>
</section>
```

They are scrolling by click with javascript

```
 jQuery.fn.extend({
  scrollTo : function(speed, easing) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var targetOffset = $(this).offset().top;
      $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, speed, easing);
    });
  }
});

$('.next-section').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
        $next = $this.parent().next();

    $next.scrollTo(150, 'linear');
});

$('.prev-section').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
        $prev = $this.parent().prev();

    $prev.scrollTo(150, 'linear');
});
```

In second section I have some svg, animated with CSS, but I would like to start the animation when the svg is visible. How should I do that?

Comment: please make a fiddle, that would be easier for us to see exactly what you mean and help with code... jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k29pwt5t/ but scrolling and svg-animation doesn't work there... There is a button on left top "Next section" that makes the page scroll down.

Comment: Did you try the jquery selector (':visible')? it is supposed to select a visible element... you should maybe use some $(function(){}) where you test if your element's position is located between window top and bottom...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a "complete" function to jQuery `animate()`. That complete function gets called when the animation completes.  In that function you could add a class to your SVG that triggers the animation.